# Prove that $N$ is subgroup of $G$ and $G/N \cong \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Problem**

Let $G$ be the set of all functions with $D_G$ be the domain of $G$ where $D_G=[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ and $C_G$ be the codomain of $G$ where $C_G=\mathbb{R}$, that defined by $G=\lbrace f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f: function \rbrace$.
Defined the "+" operation in $G$ by
$(\forall f_1,f_2 \in G)(\forall x \in [0,1])$,

$(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$,

such that $G$ is a group under addition.

If $N = \lbrace f \in G | f(\frac{1}{4})=0 \rbrace$, show that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G / N \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$.

Here I tried so far. Please correct me if I wrong. Thanks for help in advanced.

**My Solution**

First, we'll show that $(\forall f_1,f_2\in N).f_1f_2^{-1} \in N \Rightarrow N$ subgroup of $G$.

Let $f_1,f_2 \in N$. Since $G$ group, then
$f_2^{-1} = -f_2 \in N$. Thus,
$f_1f_2^{-1}: (f_1 + (-f_2))(x)$

$=f_1(x)-f_2(x) = 0 \in N$, where $x=\frac{1}{4}$. Hence, $N$ is subgroup of $G$.

Next, we'll show that $G/N \cong \mathbb{R}$. Consider the mapping $k:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$k(f)=f(\frac{1}{4})$.

Note that $k(f_1+f_2)=(f_1+f_2)(\frac{1}{4}) = f_1(\frac{1}{4}) + f_2(\frac{1}{4})$. Thus, $k$ is a homomorphism.
Next, pick any real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the constant function $f(x)=r, \forall x \in [0,1]$.
Then, $k(f)=f(\frac{1}{4})=r$. So, $k$ is surjective. Next,

$Ker \ k = \lbrace f \in G | k(f)=0 \rbrace$

$= \lbrace f \in G | f(\frac{1}{4}) = 0 \rbrace = N$.

Then, let $f_1,f_2 \in G$. Suppose $k(f_1)=k(f_2) \Rightarrow f_1(\frac{1}{4}) = f_2(\frac{1}{4})$. Thus, $f_1 = f_2$. Hence, $k$ is injective.

Hence, $G/N \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mostly correct, but you should not have written that “Since $G$ group, then
$f_2^{-1} = -f_2 \in N$”. That's just a matter of notation: since we are working with an *abelian* group, it is more natural to use $-g$ to represent the inverse of $g$ rather than $g^{-1}$. And that would still be true if you were working with, say the semigroup os all polynomials in one variable with cofficients in $[0,\infty)$ (endowed with the usual addition), which is not even a group.

Comment: So, what should I do to be correct?

Comment: Let $f_1,f_2 \in N$. Then, $f_2^{-1} = f_2 \in N$. Like this?

Comment: No; that is just plain wrong. Just write that if $f_1,f_2\in N$, then $f_1-f_2\in N$ because…

Comment: because what....?

Comment: Because $f_1\left(\frac14\right)-f_2\left(\frac14\right)=0-0=0$.

Comment: great i got it now

Comment: wait, is the mapping from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $k(f)=f(\frac{1}{4})$ true?

Comment: Sure! If that was wrong, I would have said it.

Comment: okay. and, is $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \in N$?

Comment: what can I say about it?

Comment: Since the $0$ function maos $\frac14$ into $0$, yes.

Comment: sorry..........? do you mean, since $\frac14 \rightarrow 0$, so $0\in N$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.